# How do you transform the output of keras NN outside backpropagation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, customization

I have raw 1d data on one side of a NN, and 1d labels on the other. Input data is transformed by going through layers with trainable parameters and specific activation function. I want to add a final transformation using an external algorithm that I don't want to train (only the parameters in the previous layers are to be trained).
How can I do that?

**UPDATE:**
Before implementing the external algorithm using subprocess, I give it a try with a simple test to output just a constant (1.0). This is the code:

```
inputs=keras.Input(shape=(174,1))
labels=padded_label
x = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=4,kernel_size=8,strides=1,input_shape=(174,1),padding='same')(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
def grande(x):
    return np.ones((x.shape))
predictions=keras.layers.Lambda(grande,trainable=False)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

where the labels are vectors of shape (174,1) with values either 0 or 1.
This doesn't work and throws error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-b23e29737fa2> in <module>()
      8     #return sp.check_output('echo 1.0',shell=True)
      9     return np.ones((x.shape))
---> 10 predictions=keras.layers.Lambda(grande,trainable=False)(x)
     11 model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
     12 model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine    /base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    701 
    702       if not in_deferred_mode:
--> 703         outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    704         if outputs is None:
    705           raise ValueError('A layer\'s `call` method should return     a Tensor '

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in call(self, inputs, mask)
    707     if generic_utils.has_arg(self.function, 'mask'):
    708       arguments['mask'] = mask
--> 709     return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
    710 
    711   def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):

<ipython-input-35-b23e29737fa2> in grande(x)
      7     print(x)
      8     #return sp.check_output('echo 1.0',shell=True)
----> 9     return np.ones((x.shape))
     10 predictions=keras.layers.Lambda(grande,trainable=False)(x)
     11 model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in ones(shape, dtype, order)
    201 
    202     """
--> 203     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
    204     multiarray.copyto(a, 1, casting='unsafe')
    205     return a

TypeError: __index__ returned non-int (type NoneType)
```

How can I give the proper shape to the output?

Comment: This can be done using Keras Functional API. It offers high flexibility while building models. https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Lambda** layer ([link](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda)) which can be used to create custom transformations without adding any new trainable weights.